# ConstraintLayout Barrier not visible in design view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout, androidx

I'm trying to add a barrier to my `ConstraintLayout` in Android Studio but it is not showing up the way it should in design view.

I have been following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/Ngz5cgLC7m4), but I can't get things to work properly.

I'm currently using:

- Android Studio 3.1.1
- `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3`

Things I have tried:

- Invalidate caches/restart
- Removing the attribute `tools:layout_editor_absoluteX`
- Fiddling around!

Here's my `test.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                              android:id="@+id/barrier2" app:barrierDirection="end"
                                              app:constraint_referenced_ids="button,button2"
                                              tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="411dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

In design view, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIHRK.jpg)

The barrier is stuck to the edge of the layout and doesn't move no matter what I do. If I set `barrierDirection` `start` or `left` it is not visible at all. If I set `end` or `right` the dashed line shows up but is stuck to the left side of the layout.

Barriers [seem to work fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INImL.jpg) in another project started from scratch, but this uses the `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` rather than the `androidx` library's.

Comment: I have the same issue with barriers created from com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrading to version `2.0.0-alpha3` solved the issue for me.

Comment: tested working on 2.0.0-alpha3. interesting to note that design view is broken for 2.0.0-beta3

Comment: confirm, `2.0.0-beta3` > `2.0.0-alpha3`, but error is at `2.0.0-beta3`

Answer (score 2):

When I upgraded constraintLayout library from version `2.0.4` to `2.1.3`, the barriers messed up.

I changed the width and height of my barriers as follow and the problem resolved.

Before:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/myBarrier"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="end"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView1,textView2,textView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

After:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/myBarrier"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

It just happened to me as well. What fixed it for me was simply closing Android Studio and open it up again.

You can also upgrade to version `2.0.0-alpha3`

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the barriers to show either, until I took the layout name out of the
app:constraint_referenced_ids list. Then the barrier appeared.